# Query ISODate time in perl

Tags: perl, mongodb

I have an application that I need to be able to query date ranges in the following query works via the mongoshell but I cannot for the life of me reproduce it via the perl MongoDB driver

```
db.matches.find({ last_seen: { $gte: new Date("2014-05-15T00:00:00.000Z")}});
```

my intial perl query looked like (I know naive)

```
$matches->find({ last_seen => { '$gte' => "new Date(\"2014-05-15T00:00:00.000Z\")"}});
```

an example of the data is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5365e47c183aa8df9dee7558"),
    "count" : NumberLong(21),
    "matches" : [ 
        "Team 2", 
        "Team 2", 
        "Team 2", 
        "Team 1", 
        "Team 1", 
        "Team 1", 
        "Team 2", 
        "Team 1", 
        "Team 1", 
        "Team 2", 
        "Team 1", 
        "Team 2", 
        "Team 1", 
        "Team 1", 
        "Team 1"
    ],
    "player1" : "Team 1",
    "player2" : "Team 2",
    "last_seen" : ISODate("2014-05-17T08:16:05.000Z")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with most language implementations you use the native "date" types to your language implementation rather than strings. MongoDB stores the date (`ISODate`) as an actual BSON repraesentation ( actually a timestamp ) that the date type will be serialized into.

The [MongoDB](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB) driver for Perl supports [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) and [DateTime::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime%3a%3aTiny) for serialization and deserialization:

```
my $cursor = $matches->find({
    last_seen => { 
       '$gte' => DateTime->new( year => 2014, month => 5, day => 15 )
    }
}
```

Or however you are going to actually obtain the date object you use to compare.

See [Dates](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/DataTypes.pod#Dates) in the [Data Types](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/DataTypes.pod) section of the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This works, so now I need to translate it to Mango as evidently it handles it completely different :(