# insert mongo objects into perl array

Tags: mongodb, perl

Apologies if this is a newbie question. I'm very new to perl.

I have a series of strings read from a DB that contain queries, some of which are for mongodb and are in json format (loosely).
I am trying to read in those strings and run them on the appropriate DB by modifying an existing perl script that does something quite similar for MySQL queries.

i.e. read the json string, decode it into an array, and then run it in mongodb.

The simple case is working fine.
The problem is that certain data types (e.g. ISODate) need to be converted to perl objects before the query can be run. for example:

```
my $qstr = 'MONGOQUERY[
    {
        $match: {
         "lastModifiedDate": "ISODate("2016-08-10T04:55:46.053+0000")"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
           name:1
        }
    },
]';

$qstr=~s/MONGOQUERY//gs;

my $qarrayref = JSON::PP->new->allow_nonref->relaxed->allow_barekey->loose->decode($qstr);

my $mongores = $collection->aggregate( $qarrayref,{ allowDiskUse => 1 } );
```

my workaround is to find and replace all instances of those specified datatypes (Timestamp,ISODate, NumberDecimal,NumberLong,NumberInt,Symbol) in the array with appropriate matching perl objects before I run the query, but as the arrays are not necessarily consistent depths, I'm not sure how to go about this. any ideas or alternate workarounds?

Not that it would work any better, but note that if I remove the quotes and have:

```
"lastModifiedDate": ISODate("2016-08-10T04:55:46.053+0000")
```

the json decode part doesn't even work.

Comment: Why can't you simply pass in the value as a string?
IIRC the ISODate function should be understood by MongoDB, right?

Comment: i've tried, but when i use:
"lastModifiedDate": "ISODate("2016-08-10T04:55:46.053+0000")"
it seems  to try to compare it to the string
"ISODate("2016-08-10T04:55:46.053+0000")"
instead of the actual date.
if that would work, it would be ideal, but as indicated by the below link, it doesn't
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709428/query-isodate-time-in-perl

Comment: Even if you use a scalar reference? As in `\qq{ISODate(2016-08-10T04:55:46.053+0000")}` ?

Comment: ISODate() is a helper function in Javascript in the shell.  It's not parsed by the database.  For Perl, you'll want to create a supported datetime object: see [MongoDB::DataTypes](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/DataTypes.pod#Dates)

Comment: @xdg, i assumed that was the case (though i hoped for an alternative), but how do i iterate through the array to replace every instance of ISODate with a new datetime object? could you provide a sample bit of code for doing that?

Comment: it turns out that there is an easy alternative for dates, namely replace 'ISODate(...)' with '{$dateFromString: {dateString:...}'
unfortunately, that only works in the newest versions of mongo, and i'm running on an older one, and can't upgrade for now. still hoping for a general solution as i mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought there'd be an easy module on CPAN to recursively walk a structure and let you transform values, but as I didn't find one, I wrote a new one: [Data::Visitor::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Visitor::Tiny).

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Data::Visitor::Tiny;
use Time::Moment;

my $ref = [
    {
        '$match' => { "lastModifiedDate" => "ISODate(\"2016-08-10T04:55:46.053+0000\")", }
    },
    { '$project' => { name => 1 } },
];

my $visitor = sub {
    my (undef, $valueref) = @_;

    # skip over values that are just nested hash/array refs
    return if ref;

    # match values you want to replace
    return unless /^ISODate\("([^"]+)"\)$/;

    # convert captured string to Time::Moment
    $$valueref = Time::Moment->from_string($1, lenient => 1);
};

visit( $ref, $visitor);

say Dumper($ref);
say "Date parsed as: " . $ref->[0]{'$match'}{lastModifiedDate};
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            '$match' => {
                          'lastModifiedDate' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'R¸=œ���@∑(����')}, 'Time::Moment' )
                        }
          },
          {
            '$project' => {
                            'name' => 1
                          }
          }
        ];

Date parsed as: 2016-08-10T04:55:46.053Z
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks xdg, i was also surprised not to find something for the traversal.

with a little help from the guys at perlmonks i also wrote something (see below).

like i mention in the comments a better solution is to replace 'ISODate(...)' with '{$dateFromString: {dateString:...}}' since that can be done in the string itself, but as a more general solution that also works for older versions of mongo:

```
#get rid of comments
$qstr=~s/[\/][\/](.*?)$//gms;
#handle specially declared datatypes
$qstr=~s/MONGOQUERY//gs;
$qstr=~s/ISODate\("([^)]*?)\)/"ISODate$1/gs;
$qstr=~s/NumberDecimal\(([^)]*?)\)/$1/gs;
$qstr=~s/NumberLong\(([^)]*?)\)/$1/gs;
$qstr=~s/NumberInt\(([^)]*?)\)/$1/gs;
#add qr flag for regexes
$qstr=~s/[\/]([\.\^].*?)([^\\])[\/](i?)/"qr\/$1$2\/$3"/gs;

my $qarrayref = JSON::PP->new->allow_nonref->relaxed->allow_barekey->loose->decode($qry);
my $rlimit=50;
repl_mongo(\@{$qarrayref},$rlimit);

    sub repl_mongo{
        if($_[1]>0){
            if(ref($_[0]) eq 'ARRAY'){
                foreach my $item(@{$_[0]}){
                    repl_mongo($item,$_[1]-1 );
                }
            }elsif(ref($_[0]) eq 'HASH'){
                foreach my $key (keys %{$_[0]}){
                    repl_mongo($_[0]->{$key},$_[1]-1 );
                }
            }else{
                if(index($_[0],"ISODate") >= 0){
                    $_[0] =~s/ISODate//gs;
                    if(index($_[0],"Z") >= 0 || index($_[0],"+")){
                        $_[0] =Time::Moment->from_string($_[0], lenient => 1);
                    }else{
                        $_[0] =Time::Moment->from_string($_[0] . 'Z', lenient => 1);
                    }
                }
                #clean up regexes
                if(index($_[0],"qr/") >= 0){ 
                    $_[0] =~s/qr[\/](.*?)([^\\])[\/](i?)$/$1$2/s;
                    if($3=='i'){
                        $_[0] = qr/$_[0]/i;
                    }else{
                        $_[0] = qr/$_[0]/;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

my $mongores = $collection->aggregate( $qarrayref,{ allowDiskUse => 1 }
```